# How can I solve "There should be exactly one item with [DropdownButton]'s value: null." error in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I want to get some details from database and put that values to dropdown menu. I have successfully got the information that I want to put on dropdown from database and put it into dropdown list.

But when I tried to select one item from dropdown list, it shows this error.

> There should be exactly one item with [DropdownButton]'s value: null.
> Either zero or 2 or more [DropdownMenuItem]s were detected with the same value

Here is the code I wrote so far.

**Variables**

```
var supplier;
var _supplierDetails = [];
```

**Init Method**

```
@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  getSupliers();
}
```

**Get Suppliers**

```
void getSupliers() async {
final responseSup =
    await http.get(Uri.parse('http://170.14.0.0:8020/supplier/'));
final jsonDataSup = jsonDecode(responseSup.body) as List;
print(jsonDataSup);

setState(() {
  _supplierDetails = jsonDataSup;
});
}
```

**DropDown menu implemented**

```
DropdownButton(
     hint: Text('Select Supplier'),
     items: _supplierDetails.map((list) {
         return DropdownMenuItem(
             child: Text(list['Name']),
                value: list['id'].toString(),
              );
            }).toList(),
            onChanged: (value) {
              setState(() {
                supplier = value;
              });
            },
            value: supplier,
)
```

Can someone help me to fix this issue please?
Thank you

Comment: you want to get data from API and display it into dropdown?

Comment: @RavindraS.Patil Hi Ravindra, I have already get and displayed it into dropdown. But when I selected an item from dropdown, app will crash and it shows me above error. Basically I need to select that displayed item from dropdown.

Comment: Can you print the values in you _supplierDetails list?
It seems there are more than one item where item['id'] is null. DropdownButton need all it's items to have a unique value.

Comment: @Tanguy Yes, Tanguy. I have already checked it. All values show in the console

Comment: @New Guy Can you edit your question so we can have a look at them?

Comment: @Tanguy I could solve the issue. As you said, issue was with 'id'. It should be '_id'. Please add it as answer. I will make it as resolved. Thank you for helping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems there are more than one item where `item['id']` is null. DropdownButton need all it's items to have a unique value